# Javascript div popup Not working in IE9 standard but does work in other modes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Having trouble with my site and IE9, if i change the compatability mode to anything other than IE 9 standard my login popup works however when in IE9 standard which is the defult it does not work. I think the best way to look at this is to try it yourself. [My Site](http://aliahealthcare.com/NEWHOME.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have IE9 handy, but a guess would be that it might be falling over due to a JavaScript error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'popup' of null`. This error is occurring because the point at which you're creating a Popup for `popup_4`, the DOM element for `popup_4` doesn't exist yet.

You could fix that by moving the `popup_4` div above the script block that's creating the Popup objects.

Comment: that doesnt seem to be the issue, i moves it and yet still no popup, this works in all browsers and even older versions of IE, just not ie9!